# Power BI Measure to countrows of related values several related tables deep

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I need to create a measure for a card that will count the total number of Question Groups that exist for each person using the tables below.

I've tried the following but it's returning the result 10, instead of the expected result which should be 6. (George = 2, Susan = 1, tom = 1, bill=1, sally =1, mark =0, jason=0)

```
Measure = COUNTROWS(NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(People,Questions),'Question Groups'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Table: People

| PeopleID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | George |
| 2 | Susan |
| 3 | Tom |
| 4 | Bill |
| 5 | Sally |
| 6 | Mark |
| 7 | Jason |

Table: relPeopleQuestions

| PeopleID | QuestionID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 8 |

Table: Questions

| Question ID | Question name | Questiong Group ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | How are you? | 1 |
| 2 | Favorite Color? | 2 |
| 3 | Favorite Movie? | 2 |
| 4 | Sister's Name | 3 |
| 5 | Brother's Name | 3 |
| 6 | What is your birthdate? | 1 |
| 7 | What City do you live in? | 1 |
| 8 | Favorite game? | 2 |

Table: Question Groups

| Question Group ID | Question Group Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Assorted |
| 2 | Favorites |
| 3 | Relatives |

A working example file can be obtained [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bu9g5zbQGFmOCufmVT_vox4dBWFNifdg/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2):

A distinct count on the `Question Group ID` from the `Questions` table would seem to be sufficient, e.g.

```
MyMeasure =
VAR MyTable =
    SUMMARIZE (
        People,
        People[Name],
        "Count", DISTINCTCOUNT ( Questions[Question Group ID] )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( MyTable, [Count] )
```

Comment: This seems to work but when applied to a data set of several thousand rows, it doesn't return the correct count.

Comment: Can only suggest you attempt to determine a small, reproducible dataset for which it doesn't work.